# Where can I set the path of the WMD menu icon image?

Tags: markdown, wmd

I've used [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) for `<textarea>`, but it seems I don't get the path of where I've to set the path of the image icon. And how could I edit its CSS code? Though I tried it with Firebug, I didn't get it . =(

[image]

Or where do I've to place the menu icon image? I normally placed it under `/public/images`.

Answer (score 2):

The path to images has to be set in the wmd.css file, in the [.wmd-button descriptor](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/wmd.css#L74). The path has to be relative to the location of the css file.

For instance, if your web site hierarchy looks like this, and provided you've stored the "wmd.css" file in the "css" folder and the "wmd-buttons.png" file in the "images" folder.

> ```
> web_site
>  |_public
>  |_images
>  |_css
>  |_...
> ```

You'd have to change the path to one of the following:

- *Relative path version:*

```
background-image: url(../images/wmd-buttons.png);
```

- *Absolute path version:*

```
background-image: url(/images/wmd-buttons.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

The icons are in [wmd-buttons.png](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/raw/master/images/wmd-buttons.png) file.

You can find it in images folder of [derobins version of wmd](http://github.com/derobins/wmd).